# XCode 6.3 bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6

I am working with XCode 6.3 & Swift.

I have just added a few view controllers in my storyboard & added the custom classes & set the respective custom classes in identity inspector.

[image]

But while I run the app it shows **Unknown class X in Interface Builder file.** & I am not able to interact with my custom classes.
There are few similar questions like this & I have tried all the solutions but none of them are working for me.

Comment: I had an issue with the Custom Class dropdown as well a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504634/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-newly-created-class-to-display-in-the-identity-ins

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: Trying with a different is not the solution.

Comment: Did I say it was the solution? I just said I had a similar problem and described how I got around it.

Comment: Ok got it. Plz suggest if you have any other workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode missed customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target"

To fix it, open storyboard as source code and replace this line:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID"   customClass="CustomClass"
sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

to this:

```
<viewController storyboardIdentifier="StoryboardId" id="SomeID" customClass="CustomClass"
customModule="AppName" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

Comment: Yes you right. But in my case when I opened my project the next day it was working properly:)

Answer (score 2):

All my viewControllers were ok, but I searched through he whole storyboard file and found this:

```
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC" customClass="end">
```

Removing the custom class got rid of the error:

```
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
```

No idea why this custom class was there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my Macbook and all modules started to populate in the Custom Class box. No created classes were showing in the dropdown box.

I'm on Xcode 7.0.1, OSX 10.10.5 on a 2015 Macbook Pro. That was a really annoying error to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem like a tedious thing but make sure that everywhere you have referenced the view controller it has been spelled correctly. I regrettably spent a lot of time attempting all of the suggestions to fix the error and it turned out to be a simple spelling mistake!

Before:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[FormApplicationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormApplicationviewController" bundle:nil];
```

After:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[FormApplicationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FormApplicationViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.